# Can't download c4 dataset with Dataflow in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, apache-beam, tensorflow-datasets, dataflow

I want to download the c4 dataset. As per the instructions page: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/c4, it's recommended to use dataflow. I followed the steps described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/beam_datasets in google colab.

Packages:

```
!pip install -q tensorflow-datasets
!pip install -q apache-beam[gcp]
```

This is the cell I'm trying to run in colab

```
%env DATASET_NAME=c4/en
%env GCP_PROJECT=......
%env GCS_BUCKET=gs://c4-dump
%env DATAFLOW_JOB_NAME=c4-en-gen

!echo "tensorflow_datasets[$DATASET_NAME]" > /tmp/beam_requirements.txt

!python -m tensorflow_datasets.scripts.download_and_prepare \
  --datasets=$DATASET_NAME
  --data_dir=$GCS_BUCKET \
  --beam_pipeline_options="runner=DataflowRunner,project=$GCP_PROJECT,job_name=$DATAFLOW_JOB_NAME,staging_location=$GCS_BUCKET/binaries,temp_location=$GCS_BUCKET/temp,requirements_file=/tmp/beam_requirements.txt"
```

It's pretty much the same code as in the tutorial. But there is no dataflow job created in the Dataflow tab and it looks like it's downloading locally. See output logs:

```
env: DATASET_NAME=c4/en
env: GCP_PROJECT=ai-vs-covid19
env: GCS_BUCKET=gs://c4-dump
env: DATAFLOW_JOB_NAME=c4-en-gen
2020-03-31 02:18:46.297213: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
I0331 02:18:49.098738 139869050173312 download_and_prepare.py:180] Running download_and_prepare for datasets:
c4/en
I0331 02:18:49.099436 139869050173312 download_and_prepare.py:181] Version: "None"
I0331 02:18:50.353859 139869050173312 dataset_builder.py:202] Load pre-computed datasetinfo (eg: splits) from bucket.
I0331 02:18:50.468347 139869050173312 dataset_info.py:431] Loading info from GCS for c4/en/2.2.1
I0331 02:18:50.522799 139869050173312 download_and_prepare.py:130] download_and_prepare for dataset c4/en/2.2.1...
I0331 02:18:50.560583 139869050173312 driver.py:124] Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.6/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
I0331 02:18:50.683776 139869050173312 driver.py:124] Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.6/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
I0331 02:18:51.189772 139869050173312 dataset_builder.py:310] Generating dataset c4 (gs://c4-dump/c4/en/2.2.1)
Downloading and preparing dataset c4/en/2.2.1 (download: 6.96 TiB, generated: 816.78 GiB, total: 7.76 TiB) to gs://c4-dump/c4/en/2.2.1...
```

And then a bunch of

```
Dl Completed...:   0% 0/18 [00:38<?, ? url/s]
Dl Completed...:   0% 0/18 [00:38<?, ? url/s]
Dl Completed...:   0% 0/18 [00:39<?, ? url/s]I0331 02:19:33.506697 139869050173312 download_manager.py:256] Downloading https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2019-18/segments/1555578517558.8/wet/CC-MAIN-20190418101243-20190418123243-00326.warc.wet.gz into gs://c4-dump/downloads/comm.s3_craw-data_CC-MAIN-2019-18_segm_1555iQS7Yn3hZ3JmwClTiCNY5qtVgGfQQAObrCqx7cMloOg.gz.tmp.1bbeb83abada465287dcecabb0e4f4b0...
```

Am I missing something or is it just a preparation stage? My main concern is that I can't see the dataflow job running.

Thanks!

UPD: tried the same approach with the compute instance - same result.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the `tfds-nightly` package so the raw files will be downloaded on the DataFlow workers instead of the manager. Please give version 2.1.0.dev202003312203 a try and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you don't have to do the processing yourself. We uploaded the dataset to a bucket in the Google Cloud, and also created a JSON version. More details at https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/discussions/5056.